# How to add properties to this soap wsdl android

Tags: android, ksoap2

My Soap wsdl is:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:AddTagDetails>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:objtag>

            <tem:FKPersonID></tem:FKPersonID>
            <tem:FKConferenceID></tem:FKConferenceID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:TagName></tem:TagName>

            <tem:CreatedBy></tem:CreatedBy>

            <tem:ModifiedBy></tem:ModifiedBy>

         </tem:objtag>
      </tem:AddTagDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Am using this code to add properties to respective tags.

SoapObject ad_property=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);

```
         ad_property.addProperty("FKPersonID", Integer.valueOf(userValues.get(0)));
         ad_property.addProperty("FKConferenceID", Integer.valueOf(userValues.get(4)));
         ad_property.addProperty("TagName", tagName.getText().toString());
         ad_property.addProperty("CreatedBy", Integer.valueOf(userValues.get(0)));
         ad_property.addProperty("ModifiedBy", Integer.valueOf(userValues.get(0)));
```

but am getting the exception as:

```
  07-15 02:03:29.401: WARN/System.err(583): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@450624b8)
```

how to resolve this Issue?

methodnames:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME2 = "AddTagDetails";
    private static final String NAMESPACE2 = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL2 = "http://xxxx.xxxxxx/TagService.asmx?wsdl";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/AddTagDetails"
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is am checked in soap UI.. am getting a response in that

Comment: What is the webservice method you are referring to?

Comment: Edited methodname and soapaction please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlaaast I figured out :

```
 URL u = new URL(URL2);
                 URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
                 connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

                 connection.setDoOutput(true);
                 connection.setDoInput(true);
                 connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION2);
                 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");




                 String xmldata = 

                                  "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"  xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> "+ 
                                  "<soapenv:Header/>"+

                                  "<soapenv:Body>"+
                                  "<tem:AddTagDetails>"+

                                  "<tem:objtag>"+
                                  "<tem:FKPersonID>"+ Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(0))+"</tem:FKPersonID>>"+
                                  "<tem:FKConferenceID>"+ Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(4))+"</tem:FKConferenceID>"+
                                  "<tem:TagName>"+tagName.getText().toString()+"</tem:TagName>"+
                                  "<tem:CreatedBy>"+ Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(0))+"</tem:CreatedBy>"+
                                  "<tem:ModifiedBy>"+ Integer.valueOf(JujamaMain.userValues.get(0))+"</tem:ModifiedBy>"+
                                  "</tem:objtag>"+

                                  "</tem:AddTagDetails>"+

                                  "</soapenv:Body>"+
                                  "</soapenv:Envelope>";        

                 System.out.println(xmldata);

                 OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

                 Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

                  wout.write(xmldata);

                    wout.flush();

                    wout.close();

                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("code..."+connection.getResponseCode());

                      //InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                      String result;
                  //int c;
                    while ((result=rd.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(result);


                    }
```

its working now..

thanks

Comment: @Udaykiran....Hey Uday thank u so much...ur code helped me alot...thanks a ton....

Comment: I have a problem with this code.Its working for some web services,but for some services it is retreiving the empty response. Wat's the problem?

Comment: or use Soap UI to check the response of xml in that and check the request here ..

Comment: The request is correct only,but unable to get the response...with the same request iPhone people got the response.but for me its showing empty response

Comment: thats not possible.. Can you give wsdl url I will check with soap UI and will check according to that

Comment: i checked with the soapUI...and gave the request same like the request in soapUI but getting only the first element of the xml,the remaining thing is not coming but i can able to see the entire response in soapUI.

Comment: means, so ur getting the response but soapobject parsing is not correct check my answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787543/soapobject-issues-android you will get to know

Comment: if they are inner tags , use soapobject , if only string values use SoapPrimitive

Comment: i got the response in xml format, while i tried to print the start-tags it is printing only few elements not the entire thing,the problem is i got half response only...I dont know wats the problem?

Comment: Can you just post the response of SoapUI and thing you printed, so that I can findout what exactly gng wrong

Comment: thats simple xml re..check this you can parse response http://pastebin.com/x0nPk1c5

Comment: Noprobs... have a nice day !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

```
public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, 
              String NAMESPACE, String URL) 
                 throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request

    request.addProperty("iTopN", "5"); //variable name, value. 
     //I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                   new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    //put all required data into a soap envelope

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request

    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  

    httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, 
    //use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what 
    //the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)

    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request

    SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response

    return result;

  }
```

Comment: Yes am but am getting org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@45046b68)

Comment: is the webservice url correct ...i have had seen that exception when that is not valid