# SOapObject Issues Android

Tags: android, ksoap2

Am getting Soap response using as Soap Object and retrieving properties. see this below code

```
SoapObject returnObj = (SoapObject)response.getProperty("GetAllDocumentsResult");
                 // Integer id = Integer.valueOf(returnObj.getProperty("id");

                  for(int i=0;i<returnObj.getPropertyCount();i++) {
                      SoapObject persondetails = (SoapObject)returnObj.getProperty(i);



                      SoapPrimitive videoname = (SoapPrimitive)persondetails.getProperty("PDFFileName");
```

am retrieving each videoname from persondetails object. but for some persons videoname tag is absent in response.

How to check validate condition such that if a particular property exists in soapobject ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you ca use one new thing that exists in new library from ksoap2 android

`SoapObject videoname = (SoapObject)persondetails.getPropertySafely("PDFFileName");`

if you want the string you can do something like these

```
String  videoname =persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("PDFFileName");
```

or even if tag is not there place something by default :D

```
String videoname = persondetails.getPropertySafelyAsString("PDFFileName","NOTHING");
```

if you don't have go "here http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.7/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Comment: But with upgrading 2.4 to 2.5.7 am getting other issues in responses

Comment: Some changes but the last method is real deal. thannx

Comment: I found that using `getPropertySafelyAsString(String)` can throw a `NullPointerException` so I created a helper function, `getPropertyVerySafelyAsString(SoapObject, String)` which tries the regular method but will return `null` if it catches a `NullPointerException`.  This is a workaround for a known bug in Android ksoap2: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=94

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `try catch` or with the debug check the propieties who send you